# How to make directive update when the collection sent to it is updated?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have send a directive a collection, but when I update the collection in the parent scope, the directive doesn't update the collection:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/kj4oj1aa/9/

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div item-menu datasource="customers" add="addCustomer()"></div>
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">add customer</button> Number added: {{numberAdded}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="customer in customers">{{customer.lastName}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**I supposed I need a $watch somewhere in my directive but where and how to implement it?**

directive:

```
.directive('itemMenu',function() {

    var controller = function($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        function init() {
            vm.items = angular.copy($scope.datasource);
        }
        init();
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            datasource: '=',
            add: '&'
        },
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'itemMenuTemplate',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.getTemplateUrl = function(item) {
            switch(item.kind) {
                case 'external':
                    return 'itemMenuTemplateExternal';
                case 'internal':
                    return 'itemMenuTemplateInternal';
                default:
                    return 'itemMenuTemplateUndefined';
            }
        };
    },
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using angular.copy, it won't update when the `$scope.datasource` is being updated.

You need to put a $watch on it with the parameter `true` at the end for deep watching. I assume this is your scenario (this is considered pretty expensive in terms of performance, so read up on [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) to see if you should be using some other method like $watchCollection).

```
var controller = function($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$watch('datasource', function(newVal) {
        copy(newVal);
    }, true);

    function copy(object) {
        vm.items = angular.copy(object);
    }

    function init() {
        //add other init code here
        copy(vm.datasource);
    }

    init();
};
```

Comment: Ah, ok, I had gotten this from example code and thought angular.copy() was necessary for some reason, I simply don't copy it now (`vm.items =$scope.datasource;`) and it works now the directive updates fine: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/kj4oj1aa/11/